# Salesforce Soap API on VB .NET: Attribute cannot be applied multiple times

Tags: vb.net, soap, salesforce

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 to make a VB .NET to make a WPF application for windows. I'm trying to use the Salesforce SOAP api to grab data from it. In the solution explorer I right click on my project -> Add -> Service Reference -> advanced -> add web reference. I put in the link to the enterprise WSDL file I downloaded from Salesforce. In my project I have a simple test button setup that runs this to try and login:

```
    Dim SFService = New SFAPI.SforceService
    Dim loginResult = New SFAPI.LoginResult

    loginResult = SFService.login(userID, userPass)
```

My issue is that I get some errors stating that the autogenerated *References.vb* has errors and they are as follows:

```
Error   BC30663 Attribute 'GeneratedCodeAttribute' cannot be applied multiple times.
Error   BC30663 Attribute 'SerializableAttribute' cannot be applied multiple times.
Error   BC30663 Attribute 'DebuggerStepThroughAttribute' cannot be applied multiple times.
Error   BC30663 Attribute 'DesignerCategoryAttribute' cannot be applied multiple times.
Error   BC30663 Attribute 'XmlTypeAttribute' cannot be applied multiple times.
Warning     Custom tool warning: Schema could not be validated. Class generation may fail or may produce incorrect results
Warning     Custom tool warning: Schema validation error: Schema item 'simpleType' named 'FaultCode' from namespace 'urn:fault.enterprise.soap.sforce.com' is invalid. The Enumeration constraining facet is invalid - 'fns' is an undeclared prefix.   
Warning     Custom tool warning: Schema validation error: Schema item 'simpleType' named 'FaultCode' from namespace 'urn:fault.enterprise.soap.sforce.com' is invalid. The Enumeration constraining facet is invalid - 'fns' is an undeclared prefix.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

In cases where you get errors related to an attribute being applied twice, this usually means that there is a duplicate vb file somewhere. Best thing to do is to hit the icon in your solution explorer to show all files: [image: Don't lie to me button]. There's probably a file being hidden/causing a duplicate here.

Ultimately, there's duplicate attributes being seen by the compiler, which is a failure, unless you specifically allow duplicate attributes.

Comment: I started a new project and confirmed in both projects that there aren't any duplicate files. Any other thoughts? Thank you!